# Gitlab CI shell on windows only runs before_script

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My CI runner will only run a single line. I'm trying to run `npm install` prior to `eslint`. However, if I add `npm install` to the `before_script` section, then only `npm install` runs and the build reports success without ever actually running `eslint`. Are multiple commands not supported on a windows shell runner?

I also tried moving `npm install` into the `lint` job, with the same result.

I have installed the gitlab multi-runner on a windows host. Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
before_script:
  - npm install

stages:
  - test

cache:
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - node_modules/

lint:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - javascript
  script:
    - eslint **/*.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

You need to **add "call" before any npm commands** in your .gitlab-ci.yml file :

```
before_script:
  - 'call npm install'
```

It is required for all npm commands when Windows shell runner is used.

**Explanation**

npm is a shell script. So you must add *call* to execute this script in a sub shell. Otherwise an "exit" command in the npm script closes the shell launched by gitlab.

See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1025

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the default shell using cmd.exe on Windows. Changing it to Powershell seems to do the trick.